# Problem related to Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives, continuity

I found out a question that I can't figure out a way to solve it. Plz can anyone help me.
Question is,

Prove that $\exists\,C\in(0,\pi/4)\,\mathrm{s.t.}\,\tan(\pi/4+C)=3/C$

I know this should be solved using Mean Value theorem but I cant figure out the function that I should define to solve the problem.
         Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Note it is Intermediate Value Theorem that is natural to use, not MVT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use $\displaystyle\tan\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+C\big)=\frac{1+\tan C}{1-\tan C}$ to get the equivalent equation $C(1+\tan C)=3(1-\tan C)$, and 
then we can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to the function $f(x)=x(1+\tan x)-3(1-\tan x)$

on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $ f(x)=\tan \left(\pi/4+x\right)-3x$.

Comment: sry i made a mistake in the question it's actually 3/C

Comment: @Dulanga Can you see how to change this answer to fit what you want?

Comment: In which case you can change the function appropriately by adjusting the $3x$ part.

Comment: ahh takeing the reciprocral of tan is it??

Comment: Not quite. Read my comment carefully.